# Flag undefined colors and no sample present from color matching system

Tags: c++, algorithm, colors, arduino

By way of a color sensor, I am matching plastic color swatches to a pre-defined palette of colors in an array using the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) (closest distance) approach. When a color is identified, a linear actuator moves. This works well, even for fairly similar pastel colors.

However, how do I code for those situations where 1. no color swatch is in front of the sensor or 2. the color is not in the array? I need to generate a "No sample" (1.) or "No match found" (2.) message and have the actuator not moving in both cases.

As it is now, when no swatch is over the sensor, the code finds a closest equivalent from the ambient light and the actuator moves (1.), when a non-matching swatch is over the sensor, the code finds a closest equivalent and the actuator moves (2.). In both cases, nothing should happen apart from outputting the messages mentioned above.

Thanks for some hints!

```
const int SAMPLES[12][5] = { // Values from colour "training" (averaged raw r, g and b; averaged raw c; actuator movement)
  {8771, 6557, 3427, 19408,  10},
  {7013, 2766, 1563, 11552,  20},
  {4092, 1118, 1142,  6213,  30},
  {4488, 1302, 1657,  7357,  40},
  {3009, 1846, 2235,  7099,  50},
  {2650, 3139, 4116, 10078,  60},
  { 857,  965, 1113,  2974,  70},
  { 964, 2014, 2418,  5476,  80},
  {1260, 2200, 1459,  5043,  90},
  {4784, 5898, 3138, 14301, 100},
  {5505, 5242, 2409, 13642, 110},
  {5406, 3893, 1912, 11457, 120}, // When adding more samples no particular order is required
};
```

```
byte findColour(int r, int g, int b) {

  int distance = 10000; // Raw distance from white to black (change depending on selected integration time and gain)
  byte foundColour;

  for (byte i = 0; i < samplesCount; i++) {

    int temp = sqrt(pow(r - SAMPLES[i][0], 2) + pow(g - SAMPLES[i][1], 2) + pow(b - SAMPLES[i][2], 2)); // Calculate Euclidean distance

    if (temp < distance) {

      distance = temp;

      foundColour = i + 1;

    }

  }

  return foundColour;

}
```

Comment: It looks like you return 1 if you find colour 0, so I presume you could return 0 to mean *"not found"*? If so, change `foundColour=i+1` to `return i+1` and change `return foundColour` to `return 0`.

Comment: You can also avoid floating point stuff if you omit the `sqrt()` altogether and replace the 3 `pow()` calls with `(r-r0)*(r-r0) + (g-g0)*(g-g0) + (b-b0)*(b-b0)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks a lot for the floating point hint. Regarding returning 0 for not found - the problem here is that the algorithm always finds "something", because ambient light or a non-defined swatch is still "somehow similar" to one of the ones in the array.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I guess you need to define a *"minimum closeness"* or a *"maximum distance"* before you declare a match.

Comment: Or maybe fix the sensor to always look at a completely alien, readily identifiable background until a sample is placed between it and the sensor.

Comment: You may find that you achieve better accuracy in variable lighting if you convert from RGB colourspace to HSL/HSV colourspace, and just compare the observed Hue with a little table of Hues measured from your palette.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just tried no swatch in front, but that returns values that have the code matching to pale yellow and very light grey. But I just realised that with no swatch present at all, the Lux value is the common office/lab lighting Lux value, whereas any swatch in front of the sensor reflects so much light from the on-board LED that it seems one could use sub-400 Lux values to throw the "no swatch present" message.

Comment: Ok, I have to re-code to try to find out if your HSL/HSV suggestion helps to exclude "false positives" from the array. In RGB, the minimum distance is near zero, the sensor or set-up it "too good" ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When color is present or not in the table can be decided by the distance of best match. When distance of it is bigger than certain threshold then return some value that indicates "not found", for example -1 or 255.

Also store whatever the sensor senses without sample present (during calibration) and when that is the best match then return some value that indicates "no sample" for example 0.

Comment: Thanks. I have to try your idea storing the "no swatch in front" sensor values in the array as well. I just hope these values are different enough from all others to throw a match. I do not quite understand what you mean in the first paragraph though.

Comment: If the office/lab has reasonably controlled lighting, around 400 lx as commonly recommended, one can use the sensor's Lux (lx) output with an if/else to trigger "no sample", see my comment to Mark Setchell above. This does not work for ultra matt dark blue, dark grey and black. But that's no problem here, the samples aren't ultra matt. That leaves the "false positives" to solve.

Comment: Add functionality of recalibration for unusual lighting if it is issue.

Comment: Alright, a distance threshold gleaned from the calibration process works well to flag "swatch present" or "no swatch present". It actually works for very bright pastels or very dark muddy colours.